# Formula to get number between percent

Tags: math, formula, percentile

I need to calculate a % between two numbers.

```
255 = 100%
153 = 0%
```

What is the formula to get the number for 50%, using the scenery above?

Comment: `(255 - 153) * 0.5` will give you the difference to the middle (50%), then add another `153` to find the actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 50% (halfway) the formula is simply

```
result = (a + b) / 2
```

in general for a generic percentage `k` the formula is

```
result = (a*(100-k) + b*k) / 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation). Here's a snippet of python code.

```py
def lerp(a, b, t):
    """Linearly interpolates between a and b by t."""
    return (1 - t) * a + t * b

>>> lerp(153, 255, 0.5)
204.0
```